# Avoid iterating over list inside loop

Tags: apex, loop, bulkification, iteration

Hello guys I have two lists. One has contact records and other has ContentVersion records. What I need to do is that by every contact I have to create a documents and attach to them by using the LinkedEntityId of the ContentDocumentLink.

The problem is that inside the listMembers iteration I have the other interaton of the list of ContentVersion like this:

`

```
    List<Contact> listaMiembros = new List<QX_Cuenta__c>();
    listaMiembros = [SELECT Id, Name, QX_EmailContacto__c, QX_TelefonoMovil__c, QX_Rol__c FROM Contact WHERE Id IN: listMembers];

if(String.isNotBlank(filesToSend)) {
            List<ContentVersion> cvList = new List<ContentVersion>();
            List<ContentDocumentLink> cdList = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();

                for(FileDataWP file : files) {
                    ContentVersion conVer = new ContentVersion();
                    conVer.ContentLocation = 'S'; // S = Salesforce, E = External Files
                    conVer.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(file.fileContent);
                    conVer.Title = file.fileName;
                    conVer.PathOnClient = file.fileName;
                    cvList.add(conVer);
                }
            Insert cvList;

            List<ContentVersion> listCV = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id =: cvList];

            for(Contact imiembro: listaMiembros){
                for(ContentVersion  cv : listCV) {
                    ContentDocumentLink conDocLink = New ContentDocumentLink();
                    conDocLink.ContentDocumentId = cv.ContentDocumentId;
                    conDocLink.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
                    conDocLink.LinkedEntityId = imiembro.Id;
                    conDocLink.shareType = 'V'; // V = Viewer, C = Collaborator, I = Inferred
                    cdList.add(conDocLink);
                }
            }
            Insert cdList;        
        }`
```

I want to avoid the bulkify. Does anybody has a better idea?
Can someone put and example?
Thanks

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate. You're asking how to optimize a nested for loop, but in this case, a nested for loop is appropriate, assuming you want to attach all files to all contacts, which appears to be the case. If not, please [edit] your question on how it is different than the attached question, and we'll be happy to reopen your question.